# New York Convention contract

Tags: contract-law

A person A from country M meets a person B from country N. The meeting takes place in a country O. All the three countries M, N, O are a member of the New York Convention.

Can people A and B sign a contract that is normally not allowed to sign according to the local laws of the country O, however such a contract is possible to sign according to the New York Convention?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can people A and B sign a contract

It occurs to me that you are actually asking whether the signed contract will be **enforceable**. As for *signing*, people can sign whatever — a wall, a piece of toilet paper, an ass etc.

It will surely be enforceable in countries M and N. Where it was signed — in O, in outer space or on Mars — does not matter.

> not allowed to sign according to the local laws of the country O

It will then not be enforceable in O. Moreover, depending on those local laws and what the contract is, A and B might go to jail by revealing they have signed such a contract. The New York Convention won't help then.